# Yahoo marked my mail as spam and says domainkey fails

Tags: spam, domainkeys

Yahoo is marking our mail as spam. We are using PHP Zend framework to send the mail.
Mail header says that Domain Key is failed.

Authentication-Results: mta160.mail.in.yahoo.com from=mydomain.com; domainkeys=fail (bad sig); 
                        from=mydomain.com; dkim=pass (ok)

We configured our SMTP server (Same server used to send mail from zend framework.) 
in outlook and send the mail to yahoo. This time yahoo says domainkeys is pass.

Authentication-Results: mta185.mail.in.yahoo.com from=speedgreet.com; domainkeys=pass (ok);
                        from=speedgreet.com; dkim=pass (ok)

Domainkey is added in mail header on our server which is used by both outlook client and PHP client. 
yahoo recognize the mail which is sent from outlook and yahoo does not recognize the mail from 
PHP client.
As far as I know, Signing the email is done on the server side with help of domain key. 
PHP and Outlook uses the same server to sign the mail. But why yahoo handling differently? 
What I am missing here? Any Idea? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to tell the PHP framework what domain name you are signing the email as ... basically change "mydomain.com" to "speedgreet.com". I do not know anything about the framework but for signing stuff as DKIM and DomainKeys you need several things:

1. Private Key file
2. Domain (this is the domain that has the policy TXT records)
3. Selector (this is the subdomain that contains the policy TXT records, normally something like "dkim")

If you could give a bit more information on the code used to sign the message or setup signing and the full header records (in Yahoo, click the "Action" button then select "Full Header") will help.